# Finding an entire function

Tags: complex-analysis

$a.$ Find all the entire functions $f(z)$  for which there exists positive constant $M$ and $R$  and a positive integer $n$ such that $$|f(z)|\geq M |z|^n $$ whenever, $|z|>R$.

$b$. What if the word 'entire' is replaced by memomorphic in above problem $(a)$

For the first part I take $g(z)= z^n M / f(z)$
 $$|g(z)|\leq \frac{|z^n| M}{|f(z)|} \leq 1 $$

This means $g(z)$ is bounded and if $f(z)$  vanishes at some points then $g(z)$ will have isolated singularities. We can remove singularities of $g(z)$ by the Reimann Theorem.
Hence $g(z)$ is entire and bounded , then applying Liouville Theorem , $g(z)$ has to be constant.

Say $g(z) = C $ for some $C\in \mathbb{C}$

That is, $f(z)=z^n M/C$ is the required function.

Is there a right approach. I am not hundred % sure on my work.

And what about $(b)$.

Can someone help me?

Comment: How do you get rid of the singularities in the first part? Consider $f(z)=z-1$, $n=1$, $M=\frac12$, $R=2$.

Comment: $g(z) \to 0 $ as $z\to 1$ where $g(z)=z/2(z-1)$ which means the singularity is removable.

Answer (score 1):

In the first part, note that you only have a bound on $g$ for $|z| > R$, while $g$ can have poles at zeros of $f$ for $|z| < R$.  After subtracting the principal parts of those poles, you do have a constant.

Answer (score 0):

For part (a) any polynomial of degree greater or equal to n fits the restrictions.