# a question about specific entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula, entire-functions, meromorphic-functions

> Find all the entire functions $f(z)$ for which there exists positive constants $M, \:R$ and a positive integer $n$ such that 
>   $$|f(z)|\geq M.|z|^n\:\:\text{whenever}\:\:|z|>R.$$ 
>   What if the word entire is replaced by meromorphic.

I know, there are already some other answer for this problem,([Finding an entire function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992453/finding-an-entire-function)), but I have my own solution and I would like to correct it.

Since for $|z|>R$, we have $|f(z)|\geq M|z|^n$, $f$ does not vanish at any point $z$ for which $|z|>R$.

Hence all zeros of $f(z)$ are in $\overline{D(0,R)}$. As zeros of $f(z)$ are isolated and $\overline{D(0,R)}$ is compact, so $f$ has finitely many zeros in this disc. Let's say zeros of $f(z)$ are $z_1,\dots,z_m$, including their multiplicity. Define $h(z)=\frac{f(z)}{\Pi_1^m(z-z_j)}, $ (Note that ${h(z_j)\neq 0}$ ).

The function $h(z)$ is entire everywhere and it doesn't vanish anywhere, so $\frac{1}{h(z)}$ is also entire.

As, $\frac{1}{h(z)}$ is entire, so all of its derivative are entire, so they attain their maximum over $\overline{D(0,R)}$.

For $|z|>R$, we have 
$$|\frac{1}{h(z)}|\leq \frac{1}{M}.\frac{1}{|z|^n}.|\Pi_1^m(z-z_j)|\leq \frac{1}{M}.\frac{1}{R^n}. |\Pi_1^m(z-z_j)|$$

Hence, $(\frac{1}{h(z)})^{(m)}$ (the m-th derivative of $\frac{1}{h(z)}$) becomes a bounded entire fucntion ( already know it's bounded in $\overline{D(0,R)}$), so it's constant and hence $\frac{1}{h(z)}$ is a polynomial of degree at most $m$. (I haven't written proof for this part but I think similar poof for Cauchy estimation can be used to show  $(\frac{1}{h(z)})^{(m)}$ is bounded).
$$h(z)=\frac{1}{\Pi_1^k(z-p_j)}, \:\:\text{where}\:k\leq m$$

However, $h(z)$ is entire function so it doesn't have any pole so $h(z)={\text{constant}}$. Consequesntly, $f(z)$  is a polynomial with degree of greter or equal $n$, with the proper coefficient if its degree is $n$.

I think with similar proof we can show if we the word entire is replaced by meromorphic, $f(z)$ becomes rational function.

Comment: "If I differentiate m times ...": can you explain this?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I made some changes, I can explain more, if it's still unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a general result that implies your result (and the proof is not too difficult): If $f$ is entire and

$$\tag 1 \lim_{|z|\to \infty}|f(z)|=\infty,$$

then $f$ is a polynomial.

Proof: If $f$ is not a polynomial, then $g(z)=f(1/z)$ has an essential singularity at $0.$ Thus by Casorati-Weierstrass, $g(\{0<|z|<r\})$ is dense in $\mathbb C$ for all $r>0.$ But this is the same as saying $f(\{|z|>1/r\})$ is dense in $\mathbb C$ for all $r>0.$ That violates $(1).$

Comment: What is the contraction at the end?  Now $f(\{|z|>1/r\})$ is dence in $\mathbb{C}$, so given $\epsilon >0$, for $w\in \mathbb{C}$ there exists $f(z_0)\in f(\{|z|>1/r\})$ such that $|f(z_0)-w|\leq \epsilon$ and then? I can't go further!

Comment: The hypothesis on $f$ implies there exists $R$ such that if $|z|>R,$ then $|f(z)|>1.$  Thus $f(\{|z|>R\})$ does not interesect the open unit disc, and hence $f(\{|z|>R\})$  is not dense in $\mathbb C,$ contradiction